# BigQuery UNNEST duplicates values

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to create a summary of Google Analytics data: sessions, transactions and conversion rate by hour and by source property (named service in my case). I am querying a table named "ga_realtime_view" from a rollup property dataset. It is a virtual view created from the "ga_realtime_sessions_" table, which allows us to use standard SQL.

In order to have the service column, I have to use UNNEST operation. However when I do so, it duplicates all the sessions and transactions values.

Here is the query:

```sql
SELECT
EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(visitStartTime) AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris') AS Hour,
hits.sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyDisplayName AS service,
IFNULL(SUM(totals.visits),0) as sessions,
IFNULL(SUM(totals.transactions),0) as transactions,
IFNULL(ROUND((SUM(totals.transactions)/SUM(totals.visits))*100,2),0) AS conversionRate
FROM `XX.ga_realtime_view` AS session, UNNEST(session.hits) AS hits
GROUP BY
Hour,
service
ORDER BY
Hour
```

I know there has been other topics about this duplication issue, however I can't seem to find the solution in my case.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to avoid joining the table with the array (via the `, UNNEST(session.hits)`) since this has the effect of duplicating all of the totals. It's not clear what you want to do with the service names, though: if there is more than one, do you want to return an array of all of them? This is once approach:

```
SELECT
EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(visitStartTime) AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris') AS Hour,
ARRAY(
   SELECT sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyDisplayName
   FROM UNNEST(session.hits) AS hits
) AS service,
IFNULL(SUM(totals.visits),0) as sessions,
IFNULL(SUM(totals.transactions),0) as transactions,
IFNULL(ROUND((SUM(totals.transactions)/SUM(totals.visits))*100,2),0) AS conversionRate
FROM `XX.ga_realtime_view` AS session
GROUP BY
Hour,
service
ORDER BY
Hour
```

As you'll notice, though, the query now gives an error that you can't group by an array. If you expect that you will only ever have a single type of service within the hits, you can extract just one:

```
SELECT
EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(visitStartTime) AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris') AS Hour,
(SELECT MAX(sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyDisplayName)
 FROM UNNEST(session.hits) AS hits) AS service,
IFNULL(SUM(totals.visits),0) as sessions,
IFNULL(SUM(totals.transactions),0) as transactions,
IFNULL(ROUND((SUM(totals.transactions)/SUM(totals.visits))*100,2),0) AS conversionRate
FROM `XX.ga_realtime_view` AS session
GROUP BY
Hour,
service
ORDER BY
Hour
```

Comment: thanks. In fact service = source property = a website. We have different websites , each having their own GA property. So what I want to do is to have the number of transactions and sessions by hour and by website. Is that a bit clearer ?

Comment: can't edit my comment but your solution works very fine with what I wanted to do ! Thanks again